# if condition inside a sql query

Tags: mysql, if-statement

following is a part of my stored proceedure im using it to extract data from my db.

query

```
BEGIN

SET @sqlstring = CONCAT("SELECT b.ID, c.name, c.accountID,, b.total_logs, a.time_start, a.time_end ,COUNT(a.id) AS number_of_users
FROM    ",logtable," a INNER JOIN users b on a.ID = b.ID INNER JOIN accounts c on b.accountID = c.accountID
GROUP BY ID;");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlstring;
    EXECUTE stmt;

END
```

At times in the db, the `logtable(table is passed in a variable like logtable_1, logtable_2 .... )` can be non existent, currently when the perticuler table is missing it crashes and throws an error because a.time_start, a.time_end cannot have values without the log table.

but what i want is just to assign `NULL` on values `a.time_start, a.time_end` without throwing an error,

So can any body tell is there a way i could modify this code like

```
BEGIN

if logtable exists
   \\ the query

else
   \\ the query

END
```

Comment: any mysql experts!!!

Answer (score 0):

Find existence of the table by querying `information_schema.tables`. If it returns a count equals to 1 then you can proceed executing your query on the table. Otherwise go with your `Else` block.

**Sample**:

```
declare table_exists int default 0;

select count(1) into table_exists 
  from information_schema.tables
 where table_schema='your_table_schema_name'
   and table_name = 'your_table_name';

if table_exists then
  -- do something
else
  -- do something else
end if;
```